# Identifying unknown old components

Tags: components

[image]
Could anyone tell me please what the component circled is? It have 6 pin / legs, and if it not existed anymore could you please let me know replacement / similarities?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the rest of the printing, this is a bit of a guess, but I'd say they are transformers made by Pico Electronics:

https://www.picoelectronics.com/

Comment: @Enjang: Probably pulse transformers or really lightweight common-mode filters.  These are not things that break easily -- they wouldn't be what I suspected of breaking first, unless the board had seen some truly horrible voltage spikes on those inputs.